# Customer Dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL code to create a Customer Dimension.

```
ID Name File Import Date
1   XXX  12/30/2018
1   XXX  12/31/2018
1   XXX  1/1/2019
1   YYY  2/2/2019
1   YYY  3/2/2019
1   YYY  4/2/2019
2   AAA  1/1/2019
```

I want to create a Query where I can capture the distinct Name along with the History

New table

```
ID Name     Active
1  XXX        0
1  YYY        1
2  AAA        1
```

Below query give me the latest record

```
SELECT Distinct a.[ID] as CustID
,a.[Name] as CustName
FROM X as a 
inner join 
(select ID,[MaxDate] = MAX(FileImportDate) from X  group by ID   ) b 
on a.ID = b.ID 
and a.FileImportDate = b.MaxDate`
```

enter code here`

Comment: how do u decide which date you are pulling?

Comment: What is Active?

Comment: why max date for XXX but min for YYY

Comment: I think you should learn what the group by clause is for: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp and https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What have you tried to solve this yourself, and why didn't it give the result you were after?

Comment: Below query gives me the latest records     SELECT Distinct a.[ID] as CustID
,a.[Name] as CustName
FROM X as a 
inner join 
(select ID,[MaxDate] = MAX(FileImportDate) from X  group by ID   ) b 
on a.ID = b.ID 
and a.FileImportDate = b.MaxDate

Comment: Why is active = 0 for XXX?

Comment: Do you see our comments?

Comment: because the name change for ID and XXX is the old name for ID = 1

Comment: How will I create the Active column

Answer (score 1):

I'll bite...

Going by comments, this is a guess

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with ties
       ID
      ,Name
      ,Active = case when [FileImportDate] = max([FileImportDate]) over (Partition By ID) then 1 else 0 end
From  YourTable
Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Name Order by [FileImportDate] Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Name    Active
2   AAA     1
1   XXX     0
1   YYY     1
```

Here is a [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=095f0bc541d0de8228fa79210476768a)

Comment: @user6167232 Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

With `distinct` and `case`:

```
select 
  distinct t.id, t.name,
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from tablename 
      where 
        id = t.id 
        and name <> t.name 
        and fileimportdate > t.fileimportdate) then 0 
    else 1 
  end active
from tablename t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d64f2609e9276b51a9f412ff21d28f2c)
Results:

```
id  name    active
1   XXX       0
1   YYY       1
2   AAA       1
```